# SQL Server Transaction log Percent Used in Perfmon

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

I am doing some research into monitoring transaction log use using windows perfmon.

In the AdventureWorks database I have created the following statement

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Person.BusinessEntity ON

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = MAX(BusinessEntityID) FROM Person.BusinessEntity
    SET @id += 1

    INSERT INTO Person.BusinessEntity(BusinessEntityID, rowguid, ModifiedDate) VALUES (@id,NEWID(), GETDATE())

    INSERT INTO [Person].[Person]
               ([BusinessEntityID]
               ,[PersonType]
               ,[NameStyle]
               ,[Title]
               ,[FirstName]
               ,[MiddleName]
               ,[LastName]
               ,[Suffix]
               ,[EmailPromotion]
               ,[AdditionalContactInfo]
               ,[Demographics]
               ,[rowguid]
               ,[ModifiedDate])
         VALUES
               (@id,
               'EM',
               0,
               NULL,
               'Ken',
               'J',
               'Sánchez',
               NULL,
               0,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NEWID(),
               '2

009-01-07 00:00:00.000')
END
```

The query will indefinitely enter rows into `Person.BusinessEntity` and `Person.Person` until I click stop

This should cause the transaction log to grow quickly which I can monitor in perfmon

I have added the perfmon counter for percent log used and run the statement and I get the graph as follows

[image]

I am wondering why the graph goes up and down again?

I assume it goes up when the log is written to and back down as the log resizes again?

If this is true then disabling autogrowth on the transaction log in the Adventure Works database and running the statement whilst monitoring again should see the graph go up and up and then reach the top and the query terminate because it is unable to resize the log?

[image]

However, I get similar behaviour again.

Can someone explain to me why am not seeing the transaction log start to fill after turning off autogrowth? Is there something else happening here?

The database is in full recovery mode

Comment: Is your database in `SIMPLE` recovery mode?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add that to the question. It's in full recovery mode

Comment: Did you ever take full backup of this db?

Comment: Please update your question with the result of select last_log_backup_lsn
from sys.database_recovery_status
where [database_id] = db_id ('AdventureWorks');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My *suspicion* is that your database, while showing it's in `FULL` recovery mode, is actually in **pseudo-simple** mode where the database still behaves like it is still in `SIMPLE` recovery mode until a full database backup is taken.

[Paul Randal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/94938/paul-s-randal), CEO of SQLSkills.com, wrote a [blog post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/) about this recovery model called *pseudo-simple*. This is a behavior of the database that, while it may be configured to be in `FULL` recovery model, still behaves as if it was still in `SIMPLE` recovery model. You can easily test this by creating a database and setting it to `FULL` recovery model. While you can perform a lot of transactions in the database, the transaction log will get truncated, as it is with databases in SIMPLE recovery model.

Paul wrote a TSQL function that can determine if a database is truly in `FULL` recovery.  Here's the script from the above post.

```
USE [msdb];
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = N'SQLskillsIsReallyInFullRecovery')
    DROP FUNCTION [SQLskillsIsReallyInFullRecovery];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [SQLskillsIsReallyInFullRecovery] (
    @DBName sysname)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsReallyFull BIT;
    DECLARE @LastLogBackupLSN NUMERIC (25,0);
    DECLARE @RecoveryModel TINYINT;

    SELECT
        @LastLogBackupLSN = [last_log_backup_lsn]
    FROM
        sys.database_recovery_status
    WHERE
        [database_id] = DB_ID (@DBName);

    SELECT
        @RecoveryModel = [recovery_model]
    FROM
        sys.databases
    WHERE
        [database_id] = DB_ID (@DBName);

    IF (@RecoveryModel = 1 AND @LastLogBackupLSN IS NOT NULL)
        SELECT @IsReallyFull = 1
    ELSE
        SELECT @IsReallyFull = 0;

    RETURN (@IsReallyFull);
END;
GO
```

And here is an example of utilizing that function (replacing 'test' with your database name).

```
select MSDB.DBO.SQLskillsIsReallyInFullRecovery ('test')
```

There is also a Powershell script written by Edwin Sarmiento that provides the same information:

[Check If a SQL Server Database Is In Pseudo-Simple Recovery Model Using Windows PowerShell](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2974/check-if-a-sql-server-database-is-in-pseudosimple-recovery-model-using-windows-powershell/)

My suggestion would be to take a `FULL` backup of the database and retry your tests.

Comment: I knew the concept, but had never heard of pseudo-simple. Great answer!

Comment: This has fixed it. The query returned 0, then I did a full backup and then the query returned 1. Thanks, I've never known this behaviour